# Find exact contours (opencv, python)

Tags: python, opencv

I am using OpenCV+Python to detect and extract eyeglasses from a (face) image. I followed the line of reasoning of this post(https://stackoverflow.com/questi...) which is the following:

1) Detect the face

2) Find the largest contour in the face area which must be the outer frame of the glasses

3) Find the second and third largest contours in the face area which must be the frame of the two lenses

4) Extract the area between these contours which essentially represents the eyeglasses

However, `findContours()` does find the outer frame of the glasses as contour but it does not accurately find the frame of the two lenses as contours.

My results are the following:
[Original image,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrjnH.jpg) [Outer frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vosWO.jpg),
[Left lens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzLCO.jpg)

My source code is the following:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('Luc_Marion.jpg')

RGB_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)    
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Detect the face in the image
haar_face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
faces = haar_face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_img, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=8);

# Loop in all detected faces - in our case it is only one
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(RGB_img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0), 1)

        # Focus on the face as a region of interest
        roi = RGB_img[int(y+h/4):int(y+2.3*h/4), x:x+w]
        roi_gray = gray_img[int(y+h/4):int(y+2.3*h/4), x:x+w]

        # Apply smoothing to roi
        roi_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(roi_gray, (5, 5), 0)

        # Use Canny to detect edges
        edges = cv2.Canny(roi_gray, 250, 300, 3)

        # Dilate and erode to thicken the edges
        kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
        edg_dil = cv2.dilate(edges, kernel, iterations = 3)
        edg_er = cv2.erode(edg_dil, kernel, iterations = 3)

        # Thresholding instead of Canny does not really make things better
        # ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(roi_blur, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
        # thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur_edg, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 115, 1)

        # Find and sort contours by contour area
        cont_img, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edg_er, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        print("Number of contours: ", len(contours))
        cont_sort = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

        # Draw largest contour on original roi (which is the outer 
        # frame of eyeglasses)
        cv2.drawContours(roi, cont_sort[0], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

        # Draw  second largest contour on original roi (which is the left 
        # lens of the eyeglasses)
        # cv2.drawContours(roi, cont_sort[1], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    plt.imshow(RGB_img)
    plt.show()
```

How can I detect exactly the contour of the left lens and of the right lens of the eyeglasses?

*I hope that it is clear that my final output must be the eyeglasses themselves as my final goal is to extract the eyeglasses from a face image.*

Comment: Add your output image and How you would like the ouput to be

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think that I am pretty accurate about what I want my output to be. My final output must be the eyeglasses themselves so essentially I want to extract the eyeglasses from a face image.